# How to get stable current from three-phase alternating?

Tags: current, generator, three-phase, bridge-rectifier

I have [this](https://aliexpress.ru/item/4000159022005.html) generator.

How can I convert a three-phase AC voltage into a DC voltage?

I know that I can use a diode bridge to rectify the voltage, but how can I use it with a three-phase generator?

Comment: By "Stable" do you mean DC? Possible with 6 diodes.

Comment: The usual diode bridge is a two-phase one. Can you figure out how to add an extra phase?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stable voltage supply then a stable current is produced when the load is a stable resistance, \$R\$. This is embodied in Ohm's law; \$I = \frac{V}{R}\$

If you 3-phase rectify then you'll get a fairly stable DC voltage like this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Waveform_fullwave_rectifier3.png). If that isn't stable enough then you may need to add a reservoir capacitor to smooth it out.

<sub>What "stable" ultimately means is one thing to one person and another thing to someone else.</sub>